# Javascript split can keep splitted value?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

In Javascript :

```
var myString = "This is my string";

console.log(myString.split(/(\s)/));
```

Output : `["This", " ", "is", " ", "my", " ", "string"]`

```
console.log(myString.split(/\s/));
```

Output : `["This", "is", "my", "string"]`

Why is this happening ?

Comment: If you group the split pattern then it is placed in return array

Comment: [*If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. However, not all browsers support this capability.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: ^ If you don't know why a function behaves like it does, read its MDN documentation first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two regexs you're using are only slightly different.

`/(\s)/` has a capture group of `\s`, so when used with `split()` it will add the anything found in the capture group to the array.

The regex `/\s/` has no capture group, so `split()` ignores the matches and does not add them to the array.

Similarly, if you execute:

```
var myString = "This is my string";

console.log(myString.split(/(my)/));  //includes matched capture group in results
console.log(myString.split(/my/));  //ignores matches
```

Will output:

> ["This is ", "my", " string"]
>   ["This is ", " string"]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a "capturing" group for the split pattern then the assumption is that probably you're interested in the group and therefore Javascript adds the group to the result.

If for example you use a "non-capturing" group instead then the result of the split is the same as when not using a group at all..

```
"This is my string".split(/(?:\s)/) → ["This", "is", "my", "string"]
```

Indeed there can be cases in which you may need a capturing group for the match (e.g. if you need a back-reference) but you're not interested in the separators. The workaround in those cases is to simply keep every other element of the result.